# How to mount an Apple device from Linux?

Tags: mount, data-recovery, rescue, ddrescue, apple

I would like to mount an Apple iPad to my Linux device, to make a jpeg or ddrescue recovery on it. How I would do this with an Apple device?

Comment: linux has imobiledevice but i don't thing you'll be able to access the files on your ipad unless you jail break it.

Comment: Physical acquisition of iOS devices? If you find a way to do it and avoid the encryption, you could become forensic investigator of the year. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the block device on Apple directly, it is forbidden by the OS, on which you don't have a root access, despite that you've purchased it and it is yours. To be able to do these, you have to jailbreak it (I intentionally don't use the word "crack", because it is your property). It is hard. Although the OS of the Apple mobile devices, the iOS, is based on a Unix variant (OS X, which is based on freebsd), it doesn't mean that you would have the freedom of the unixes on it, its exact opposite is the truth.

Better solution would be to use some application-level thingy (i.e. to copy the files with usb or wifi).

If you have some electronical affinity, also soldering out the ssd chip from it would be a solution, although it doesn't solve the problem that their whole disk is encrypted (note: being the legal owner of the device, you are still not allowed to decrypt its content).

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks for the grammar fixes :-) Although I don't think the Apple would deserve the defensive deletion of my last paragraph. They are more dark as the micro$oft.

Comment: While I personally agree, this is not the place for that sort of soapbox.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Well, I personally accept it.